# Diagnostics and usage data option disabled

Tags: windows-10

I am running Win10x64 Home. (So no gpedit.msc)

I have previously used http://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10 to change some Windows 10 settings, but have now reverted all changes it made. It gives me this message, with the "Send your device data to Microsoft" option disabled:

[image: The Error]

I would like to enable the option in order to give feedback.

I have searched for a long time, and can't seem to find a solution. I have made some changes in the resistry, seems to make no difference. I have also checked I am using Windows Default Settings when It comes to privacy.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: By the screenshot, seems like a policy is enforced. Group policy editor might be your way (run gpedit.msc)

Comment: @Alfabravo "I am running Win10x64 Home. (So no gpedit.msc)"

Comment: @Alfabravo - Windows 10 Home cannot join a domain, so given that fact, its unlikely a group policy is to blame.  What is likely to blame is poorly written software, that claims to do something, which can already be disabled through the supplied options.

Comment: @harley_woop - Sadly this issue should be reported to the author of that program, since your inability to change it, is clearly because it change your configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound I've sent them a email.

Comment: Is your user a local or MS account? Maybe if it's local, running netplwiz, selecting your user profile, clicking on Properties and selecting the 'Group Membership' tab, select the Administrator option, Clicking apply/ok, logging out and in... to check if new permissions are available.

Comment: @Alfabravo It's a MS account; however I did try and it made no difference.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O&O Software sent me a solution, it's very simple:

Jump into regedit

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection
```

Delete the binary key  "AllowTelemetry" (Right Side)

Fixes it :-)

Comment: This has bugged me on/off for years, thank you!  PS - In in an effort to contribute something, I've converted this answer (and the one below) into a .reg file - Just copy + paste below code into notepad, save as "unlock settings.reg" (or whatever you prefer), double click the file...

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection]
"AllowTelemetry"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection]
"AllowTelemetry"=-`

Answer (score 8):

If you don't find an "AllowTelemetry" key in harley_woop's registry address, you may find it at this registry folder address instead.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection

My PC is Windows 10, Home Edition. The "Basic" option was selected, but the "Full" option was greyed out/unselectable. This is the process I used to select "Full".

1. Open *Registry Editor* with Administrator privileges
2. Copy the below address into the address bar. Press the **Enter** key.
3. Right-click on the *AllowTelemetry* DWORD > Modify
4. Change the hexadecimal number to "3" ("Full")
5. Exit *Registry Editor*
6. Restart the Settings App
7. Settings > **Diagnostics and Feedback Settings**
8. The "Full" setting should now be selected (even though greyed out). No restart should be required.

---

**AllowTelemetry DWORD Possible Options**

0 = Security (Enterprise and Education editions only)

1 = Basic

2 = Enhanced

3 = Full (Recommended)

Information Source: [Microsoft Answers Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-change-value-for-diagnostic-and-usage-data/603f5a99-8514-44de-93bc-a245a5d364cc)

Answer (score 2):

This can also be because you've disabled the service "Connected User Experiences and Telemetry".

Answer (score 2):

I had to change two keys under this location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\DataCollection
```

Both of these are `DWORD`'s.

First, this allows the user to change the setting on the "Diagnostics and Feedback" page under Windows Privacy settings:

```
MaxTelemetryAllowed = 3
```

And then. to set the level that you actually want, use this:

```
AllowTelemetry = 3
```

Where the number is:

```
0 = Security (Enterprise and Education editions only)
1 = Basic
2 = Enhanced
3 = Full (Recommended)
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I can confirm most of it, but am having trouble finding information on the `MaxTelemetryAllowed` `DWORD`, and in particular confirming that it uses the same set of numerical values and their meanings as `AllowTelemetry`.